# Como decir "lavado de dinero" de mejor manera o mas formal?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, formalidad

La realidad es que la frase "lavar dinero" es un poco común pero también un poco vulgar. Me gustaría saber como se puede referir a este tema de una manera mas formal.

Comment: Blanquear es la palabra alternativa principal, pero no creo que ninguno de los dos términos sea precisamente vulgar a pesar de que «lavar» es calco del inglés (que sepa yo, al menos).  Unas alternatives son, según la wiki, «operar con recursos de procedencia ilícita» o «legitimar capitales», pero me parecen poco manejables.

Comment: In English it is 'money laundering'. The usual word for clothes is 'washing, you have a washing machine in your house. If you take your washing elsewhere you take it to a laundry or a launderette. From this it seems to me that the alternative which rings most true is blanquear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La RAE no parece tener mucho inconveniente con decir *lavado de dinero*, ya que en su *Diccionario* la [entrada para esa palabra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N0aL8fN) tiene como ejemplo de la segunda acepción esa expresión:

> 2. m. Acción y efecto de lavar. *Lavado de ropa*. *Lavado de dinero*.

Y en [*lavar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N18qWGb) remite efectivamente a [*blanquear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5f6fTFj):

> 3. tr. blanquear (‖ ajustar a la legalidad fiscal el dinero negro).

Escuché la expresión "lavado de activos", que tal vez suene algo mejor, aunque supongo que lo que no suena bien es *lavado* y no *dinero*.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres sonar más elegante puedes decir **blanqueo de capitales**. Al menos ése es el término judicial para tal actividad en Chile. También se dice **blanqueo de activos**, aunque probablemente haya alguna diferencia técnica entre uno y otro.

Comment: Si pero justamente "blanqueo de capitales" es el hecho de hacerlo de manera legal y yo hablo sobre el lavado que es algo ilegal

Comment: Entonces es un asunto que depende del país. Acá en Chile el blanqueo de capitales es un delito. Es equivalente a lavado de dinero. Aunque todos usamos esta última forma porque no la consideramos vulgar.

Comment: @Rodrigo Para ampliar lo que señala el autor de la pregunta: en Argentina al menos, se suele usar "blanqueo" cuando el Estado te ofrece repatriar dinero, o ingresarlo al sistema financiero legal, sin hacerte demasiadas preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

**Legitimación de capitales** es la forma técnica formal que la prensa o diplomático usaría. Solo que muchas veces para mí es muy complicado entender el sentido real y específico de esos tecnicismos. Pienso que la forma más natural es la que todos entendemos: "lavado de dinero". Yo probablemente nunca diría una diferente a ésa, excepto en un entorno muy pero muy formal.
Saludos.

Answer (score -2):

lavado de capitales, lavado de activos, blanqueo de capitales u operaciones con recursos de procedencia ilícita o legitimación de capitales